# basic question: using a variable content as directory name in Linux

Tags: bash, quotes, mkdir

I want to make a new directory with the name of every zip file currently exists in a specific directory, in another one. I have written a 'for loop' for this purpose:

```
files=NL*.zip
for a in $files; do 
b=echo $a; 
sudo mkdir '/home/shokufeh/Desktop/normals/T1/"${b}"';
done
```

but it creates a directory named ${b} for the first round and make errors for next ones.
Could you please tell me what I should do?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: `b=echo $a;` doesn't do anything at all useful. You're probably thinking of something like `b=$(echo $a)`, but you don't want that either. `b=$a` does essentially the same thing, without the potential parsing bugs. But why have a second variable at all, instead of just using `$a` directly?

Comment: @Cyrus  Thank you

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you

Comment: @shs : The command `b=echo $a` would temporarily set the variable `b` to the value `echo` and then try to run `$a` as a command; so you should get an error message from this line. Since you didn't mention this, I guess that you did not paste your code exactly as you have written it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put your variable in simple quotes, there fore '${b}' will never be interpreted. Try this:

```
for a in NL*.zip; do 
  sudo mkdir "/home/shokufeh/Desktop/normals/T1/${a}";
done
```

No need for variables $files and $b.

To summarize, let's say `var=3`,

- `echo "$var"` will display `3`
- `echo '$var'` will display `$var`
- `echo "'$var'"` will display `'3'`
- `echo '"$var"'` will display `"$var"`

Hopefully this makes sense. Quotes function like parentheses and brackets.